# Add HTML tags to HTML text?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, replace, character

I'm adding **HTML tags** to specific pieces of text in a document using their character indexes, for example having this element:

```json
{
    "text": "Hello",
    "start": 0,
    "end": 5
}
```

and a text like this: `Hello world`, I'll have the following text: `<marker>Hello</marker> world`

```js
var text = Hello world
var new_text = ""
for (var i = 0; i < Array.from(text).length; i++) {
   char_text_array.push({ char: Array.from(text)[i] });
}

char_text_array.forEach(char => {
   //computing some operation buffering the piece of text contained in the new HTML marker and adding the field "last" to last character of the element 'Hello' (o)
   var match = ... //True if the character is part of an element which has to be sorrounded with an HTML tag, otherwise False
   if ("last" in char && buffer != "" and match) {
       new_text += `<marker>${buffer}</marker>`;
       buffer = "";
   }
   elif ("last" not in char && match) {
       buffer = += char.char;
   }
   else{
       new_text += char.char
   }
});
```

But if the **text is already HTML**, like:

```js
var text = "<tag1>Hello <tag2>world!!!!</tag2></tag1>"
```

I want to surround `Hello world` with a marker **without removing the other tags**. I'm able to find this result thanks to an algorithm which temporary avoids HTML tags:

```json
{
    "text": "Hello <tag2>world",
    "start": 6,
    "end": 23
}
```

But how to put the marker before `Hello` and after `world`? The result would be:

```
<tag1><marker>Hello <tag2>world</marker>!!!!</tag2></tag1>
```

But it is clear that I'm broking the right order of the tags, I think it should be:

```
<tag1><marker>Hello <tag2>world</tag2></marker><tag2>!!!!</tag2></tag1>
```

Because I have to keep `<tag2>` so I have to duplicate this tag to close it before `</marker>` and reopening before `!!!!`.

**Does an approach for adding HTML codes to other HTML text already exist?**

Comment: I guess the approach is: 1. parse the HTML into a DOM 2. pick elements/nodes according to your data and replace them accordingly (i.e. textnode "Hello" becomes element <marker>Hello</marker>, element <tag2> gets wrapped in <marker>) not an easy task for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the help of your browser's native parser? Create a HTML element, and append your HTML text into it, than get any HTML element, which contains your text, that needs to be highlighted.

```js
let fragment = document.createElement('div');
fragment.innerHTML = "<tag1>Hello <tag2>world!!!!</tag2></tag1>";

// declare a function, which will return any element by XPath
fragment.getElementByXpath = function (path) {
  return document.evaluate(path, fragment, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}
// getting the element containing the string Hello, or whichever you need
fragment.getElementByXpath('//*[contains(string(), Hello)]')
```

If the element is any different, than you container, than you can wrap up the parentNode with `marker`.
You can also simply use `parentNode.getElementsByTagName('*')` on your fragment of code, which will return an `HTML collection` containing all child elements. If the `length` is 0, than you have no inner tags.
Let me know if it helped.